# how to return the sum for each grouped date on 2 different query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Each grouped date must return different values based on the sum of rows, my query returns an error that Subquery returned more than 1 value, and this is not my expected return value, Cheers!

```
Select 
(select 
SUM(Amount) from [The Cravings Group 2013$G_L Entry]
where [G_L Account No_] in ('5010', '5011','5020','5030')
and [Global Dimension 1 Code] = 'FNB CFSI CRA KAT'
and [Posting Date] between '2016-01-08 00:00:00.000' and '2016-01-09 00:00:00.000' group by [Posting Date])
+
(select Sum(Amount)from [The Cravings Group 2013$G_L Entry]
where [G_L Account No_] between '5041' and '5047'
and [Global Dimension 1 Code] = 'FNB CFSI CRA KAT'
and [Posting Date] between '2016-01-08 00:00:00.000' and '2016-01-09 00:00:00.000' group by [Posting Date]),
[Posting Date]
from [The Cravings Group 2013$G_L Entry] 
where [Posting Date] between '2016-01-08 00:00:00.000' and '2016-01-09 00:00:00.000'
Group by [Posting Date];
```

Comment: Your query is `select (A) + (B), posting_date from....etc` .You've got 2 subqueries returning data and at least one of them is returning more than one row. What do you get when you run `A` and `B` separately.

Comment: i just thought that its possible to sum both columns from two different queries accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You subqueries are not related with the main query and they output multilines results so you can't insert a table into a row. Try this query using CASE.

```
Select 

SUM(
      CASE WHEN [G_L Account No_] in ('5010', '5011','5020','5030')
                and [Global Dimension 1 Code] = 'FNB CFSI CRA KAT'
                THEN Amount
                ELSE 0
      END 

    )
  +
SUM(
      CASE WHEN [G_L Account No_] between '5041' and '5047'
                and [Global Dimension 1 Code] = 'FNB CFSI CRA KAT'
                THEN Amount
                ELSE 0
      END 

    ) As SumOfAmounts
,
[Posting Date]
from [The Cravings Group 2013$G_L Entry] 
where [Posting Date] between '2016-01-08 00:00:00.000' and '2016-01-09 00:00:00.000'
Group by [Posting Date];
```